# can't copy NSString object to my custom object's property Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, properties

How to copy `NSString` data to my custom object's `NSString` property?
I have an object question with `NSString *text` and `KDoctor *doctor` properties.
KDoctor is an object with two properties: `NSString *name` and `UIImage *photo`.

```
self.question.doctor.name=@"abc";
NSLog(@"doctorname: %@", question.doctor.name);
```

Output is:

> doctorname: (null)

Why? How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my guess is that `question.doctor != self.question.doctor`

or

`question == nil`

or

`question.doctor == nil`

Comment: I've checked. quesion.doctor is nil :( But Why? `-(id)initWithQuestion:(KonsQuestion *)questn
{
    self.question=[[[KonsQuestion alloc] init] autorelease];
    question.text=questn.text;
    return self;
}` something wrong with my init?

Comment: @Oleg: You're not setting question.doctor anywhere that we've seen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have something wrong declaring the properly. Are you defining "question" property like this?

In your header:

```
@class KonsQuestion
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
  KonsQuestion * _question; 
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) KonsQuestion * question;
```

In the implementation file:

```
@implementation YourClass
@synthesize question = _question


@end
```

In this case you should use always self.question to use the getter and setters generated and use [_question release] in the dealloc method